# Awesomium .NET. Wpf. TitleChanged event

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, wpf, awesomium

I have a very basic application, that shows website content within the WPF app. Everything works fine, except TitleChangedEvent. Here is the code sample (XAML):

```
<Window xmlns:awe="http://schemas.awesomium.com/winfx"  x:Class="ShopChat.Desktop.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:webControls="clr-namespace:System.Web.UI.WebControls;assembly=System.Web"
    Title="{Binding ElementName=WebControl, Path=Title}" MinHeight="480" MinWidth="640">
<Grid>
  <awe:WebControl x:Name="WebControl"/>
</Grid>
```

And this is main window code-behind:

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string url = @"http://shopchat.dev";
        try
        {
            url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Url");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }

        WebControl.Source = new Uri(url);
        WebControl.TitleChanged += WebControl_OnTitleChanged;
        this.WindowTitle = "Quickchat";
    }

    public string WindowTitle
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(WindowTitleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(WindowTitleProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for WindowTitle.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty WindowTitleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("WindowTitle", typeof(string), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(null));


    private void WebControl_OnTitleChanged(object sender, TitleChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.WindowTitle = e.Title;
    }
```

I've also tried to bind to window title directly using Binding `ElementName=WebControl`. That didn't help me either.

JavaScript client code is very simple: it changes the document title on timer (setInterval).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For all those who think that the main problem is data-binding, please notice that the main problem is that "TitleChangedEvent" that is supposed to be fired when document.title in javascript client changes doesn't work as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved. TitleChanged event seemed to be insufficient. I've incorporated the usage of global js object to get the necessary behavior.

Answer (score 0):

try like this code

```
public MainWindow()
{
     InitializeComponent();

      DataContext = this;

     MyTitle = "Title";
 }
```

Then you just need in the XAML

```
  Title="{Binding MyTitle}"
```

Then you don't need the dependency property.

Then I would like to use this `INotifyPropertyChanged` with a standard property.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but this is not the main problem, the window title binding works well, however the "TitleChangedEvent" that is supposed to be fired when document.title in javascript client changes doesn't work as expected

Comment: follow this colution may be this will help you http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/41817/Implementing-INotifyPropertyChanged